# Search table where one account number is linked with two different CIN and last four digit of both CIN'S should be same

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table cmr_customer that contains two fields Account_number, CIN. Table is like that

```
Account_Number            CIN
567423                    12345678
567423                    12345678
567423                    34565678
657845                    45675678
657845                    56482536
567423                    34565678
235625                    23568445
235625                    43568445
```

And I want output like  one account_number linked with two different CIN and last four digit of both CIN'S should be same.

Required output format:

```
Account_Number            CIN
567423                    12345678
567423                    34565678
235625                    23568445
235625                    43568445
```

```sql
select Account_number, CIN , count(substr(CIN,-4) 
 from (select Account_number, CIN, substr(CIN,-4) 
       from cmr_customer
      )
group by Account_number
having count(substr(CIN,-4))=2;
```

Required output format:

```
Account_Number            CIN
567423                    12345678
567423                    34565678
235625                    23568445
235625                    43568445
```

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: But you need to add the relevant tag back in @AmitKumar . Tagging 4 different RDBMS isn't going to get your post "more views" or exposure, it's going to mean that people are going to ignore it (as tagging lots of RDBMS means that you're just adding tags for the sake of adding tags). If you don't know, or don't tell us, what RDBMS you are using then we can't supply as answer. Every RDBMS has a different SQL dialect, and we need to know which one you're using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should produce the results that you specify:

```
select distinct account_number, cin
from cmr_customer c
where exists (select 1
              from cmr_customer c2
              where c2.account_number = c.account_number and
                    substr(c2.cin, -4) = substr(c.cin, -4) and
                    c2.cin <> c.cin
             );
```